# Convergence of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider $x\in [0,1]$. I want to know if, in the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the following remains a polynomial:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$
For any finite n, this is a polynomial. But will the limiting function, whatever it is, be a polynomial? 
Kindly let me know if there is something missing in the question/ if it is too ambiguous.

Comment: the limit as $n \, \rightarrow \, +\infty$ is $\exp(x)-1$.

Comment: How can it be a polynomial if it contains infinitely many terms? The limit is closely related to the [Taylor expansion of the exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition).

Comment: As already told, the limit is far from being a polynomial. This can be connected  with, among other things, Weierstrass Theorem about the fact that any continuous function in a closed, finite interval is the *uniform* limit of a sequence of polynomials.

Comment: I know that it ultimately converges to exp(x), but what I want to know is does one really need to invoke the concept of "e" to prove that it is not a polynomial? also, @DonAntonio, thank you, but can you gimme some more details/references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your quest more clearly with your last comment below your question,@Avi_Iyer :

First, we must know the radius of convergence of the power series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\;\;\text{ is infinite , and this means this series converges for all}\;\;x\in\Bbb R$$

With the above already known, the limit function of the series (which, btw, is the *uniform* limit of it in any compact subset of the reals)  cannot be a polynomial *unless* we'd know that all but a finite number of the series's coefficients vanish, which is trivial to see they don't.

From the above we deduce the limit function of the series cannot be a polynomial even if we don't know it actually is the exponential function.

Comment: OK. I get it. So it is a polynomial only if its degree is provably finite. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes @Avi_Iyer. In order for a question to be taken out of the "unanswered questions" section, don't forget to upvote all the questions you found helpful. As the opener of the thread, you can **also** "accept" the question that you found the most helpful (but you can upvote all of the answers if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

As 
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}&=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\\& =x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots\ldots\\&=e^x-1 
\end{align}$$